# Issue calling ctx.bumps.get, Error called Option::unwrap() on a None value

Tags: pda, bump

Im starting to receive an error when calling `*ctx.bumps.get("account").unwrap();` within a method. But it only happens for some of my methods, I've reviewed my code and I cant seem to see whats going wrong.

When trying to initialize an account for a user. Below is the code I'm using.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateAccount<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        space =  RacerAccount::LEN + 8,
        seeds =[
            b"account".as_ref(),
            signer.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        payer = signer,
    )]
    pub racer_account: Account<'info, RacerAccount>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn create_account(ctx: Context<CreateAccount>, racer_name: String) -> Result<()> {
    let racer_account = &mut ctx.accounts.racer_account;
    racer_account.name = racer_name;
    racer_account.address = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
    racer_account.level = 0;
    racer_account.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("account").unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

The following is how i'm deriving the address in order to pass it into the program method.

```
const getAccountPDA = async (
  signer: PublicKey,
  programId: PublicKey = new PublicKey(IDL.metadata.address)
) => {
  return await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [Buffer.from("account"), signer.toBuffer()],
    programId
  );
};
```

When I run my tests I am receiving the following error

```
panicked at 'called Option::unwrap() on a None value'
```

The error comes from this line `racer_account.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("account").unwrap();`

To make things more confusing the following method to create a race works fine...

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(race_name: String)]
pub struct CreateRace<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        space =  Race::LEN + 8,
        seeds =[
            b"race".as_ref(),
            race_name.as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        payer = signer,

    )]
    pub race: Account<'info, Race>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn create_race(
        ctx: Context<CreateRace>,
        race_name: String,
        entry_fee: u64,
        race_rank: u8,
        race_start: u64,
        race_end: u64,
        number_of_checkpoints: u8,
        estimations: Vec<String>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let race = &mut ctx.accounts.race;
        race.name = race_name;
        race.authority = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
        race.entry_fee = entry_fee;
        race.race_rank = race_rank;
        race.race_start = race_start;
        race.race_end = race_end;
        race.registered_racers = 0;
        race.number_of_checkpoints = number_of_checkpoints;
        race.estimations = estimations;
        race.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("race").unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
```

PDA derived in my test like so

```
const getRacePDA = async (
  name: string,
  programId: PublicKey = new PublicKey(IDL.metadata.address)
) => {
  return await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [Buffer.from("race"), Buffer.from(name)],
    programId
  );
};
```

If anyone can shed some light as to why the bump doesn't exist in one of my methods but does in the other? I set the seeds, so the context should know about it...

What might I be missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because when you call `*ctx.bumps.get("account").unwrap();` anchor tries to get the calculated bump of an account passed in the context called `account` while you dont have any account with that name.

In order to fix this you have to replace that piece of code with     `*ctx.bumps.get("racer_account").unwrap();`, because you have an account called `racer_account` on the context and it has the bump calculated.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't understand it wanted the name of the account variable, not the string passed to the seed